# Array of array to manage a computing among non-adjacent lines in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm handling some data in order to calculate a mean over samples and, when having a large difference (values over mean +/- 2 standard deviations), make an interpolation, but I need a strong help!

The hard part is to select the rows for which making the calculation respect the sample they belong to. The sample identifier is placed in the first or second or third column (the third column is not present in the example below) in a dependecy logic that is not easy to manage.

My data looks like this (directly copied and pasted from my file).
The input file is also available at https://gofile.io/?c=3PLR8m.
Columns are tab separated and each identifier has a space before the characters.

```
ENTITY-CODE     XX  YY  ZZ  AA  BB  CC  att 1
/P1
 ^/A1/S1        143.07  124.05  -159.24 -160.53 0.39    3.31    15
 ^<S2       143.45  123.69  -157.19 -160.74 0.43    1.5 14.8
     +A1/S1 143.87  122.84  -157.08 -147.56 -30.37  3.07    4.9
     ^<S2   152.09  120.29  -155.42 -145.61 -67.13  0.37    3.3
     ^<S3   161.5   120.13  -153.34 -134.92 -73.39  -3.93   3.4
     ^<S4   27.76   122.15  -152.59 -103.01 -74.37  -20 2.9
     ^<S5   179.58  125.71  -153.46 -90.21  -73.6   -21.68  2.8
     ^<S6   189.23  128.85  -152.9  -86.28  -72.54  -19.89  2.4
     ^<S7   196.23  135.77  -152.82 -73.48  -75.22  -19.93  2.1
     ^<S8   195.49  147.85  -150.64 -63.59  -80.44  -32.27  1.5
 ^<S3       143.07  124.1   -157.05 -145.58 -1.81   6.34    16
     +A1/S1 142.03  123.41  -156.23 -72.07  -19.45  -0.4    5.5
     ^<S2   134.29  121.27  -153.31 -76.28  -3.92   -2.37   3.8
     ^<S3   128.55  119.39  -152.31 -73.1   6.95    0.04    2.7
     ^<S4   120.87  115.88  -150.91 -69.62  8.05    0.63    2.7
     ^<S5   115.31  112.83  -151.31 -76.97  7.45    -2.31   2.4
     ^<S6   108.54  110.71  -149.38 -86.09  5.68    -6.48   1.5
 ^<S4       143.49  123.63  -155.79 -175.31 14.3    12.22   13.7
     +A1/S1 143.5   124.75  -155.22 175.69  25.35   25.61   5.9
     ^<S2   145.63  130.57  -156.39 141.67  42.19   31.94   5.3
     ^<S3   153.77  131.23  -153.8  71.9    34.43   20.11   3.6
     ^<S4   160.99  132.18  -149.31 89.71   35.44   14.31   2.6
     ^<S5   166.86  133.6   -146.6  93.88   34.73   11.46   1.8
     +A2/S1 143.63  122.79  -155.05 65.04   4.77    -16.93  3.5
     ^<S6   144.71  122.02  -151.41 56.49   -7.71   -16.1   2.8
     ^<S6   146.83  120.14  -148.52 61.14   24.37   48.58   2.9
     ^<S6   154.06  115.65  -149.29 60.87   20.18   13.8    2.5
 ^<S5       143.32  33.32   -153.16 -127.03 8.59    9.07    12.4
 ^<S6       143.49  121.69  -150.07 -127.26 9.04    10.85   12.5
```

Basically, the rows with an identifier that follows one containing "A" in the same column need to undergo the calculation (together with the row of the "A") to check for out-of-bound values as they belong to the same sample. If, in the same column, there is another identifier containing an "A" means that is starting another group of rows which belong to another sample and need to go under another calculation.

In the example that I post here I would like a script that, starting from the first `^/A1/S1` recognizes all the rows with an identifier in the first column and make the check on the `XX`, `YY` and `ZZ` values they have.

The script should do the same also if the `+A1/S1` identifier is in the second or other columns.

In practice, everytime there is an identifier containing an "A" means that is starting a sample which futher elements have S-type identifiers in the same column (till another A-type identifier).

The number included in the S-type identifier is not relevant. Therefore, for example, the three rows which have the same identifier (next to the end of the input example) must be considered as three separate sets of values.

The format for the output should be the same of the input with the only difference of the interpolated values changed.
The interpolation should consist into the calculation of the mean and standard deviation over a sample (rows with the identifier in the same column, from one marked by an "A" till the last before another identifier in the same column having an "A") and a check if a value is over the mean +/- 2 standard deviations  (`mean±(2*dev.st)`). If so, a value is substituted with the sample mean.

In the example here I would like to obtain the same of the input except for: the `XX` value in the eighth row (27.76), which should be replaced by the mean calculated on the `XX` values from the rows of the same sample which are
the previous and next rows (which have `^<S3` and `^<S5` respectively as identifiers in the second column) and (ii) the `YY` value in the thirtieth row (33.32) which should be replaced by the mean calculated on the row which have `^<S4` and `^<S6` in the first column.

Thus, this is the output I desire.

```
  ENTITY-CODE       XX  YY  ZZ  AA  BB  CC  att 1
    /P1
     ^/A1/S1        143.07  124.05  -159.24 -160.53 0.39    3.31    15
     ^<S2       143.45  123.69  -157.19 -160.74 0.43    1.5 14.8
         +A1/S1 143.87  122.84  -157.08 -147.56 -30.37  3.07    4.9
         ^<S2   152.09  120.29  -155.42 -145.61 -67.13  0.37    3.3
         ^<S3   161.5   120.13  -153.34 -134.92 -73.39  -3.93   3.4
         ^<S4   173.59  122.15  -152.59 -103.01 -74.37  -20 2.9
         ^<S5   179.58  125.71  -153.46 -90.21  -73.6   -21.68  2.8
         ^<S6   189.23  128.85  -152.9  -86.28  -72.54  -19.89  2.4
         ^<S7   196.23  135.77  -152.82 -73.48  -75.22  -19.93  2.1
         ^<S8   195.49  147.85  -150.64 -63.59  -80.44  -32.27  1.5
     ^<S3       143.07  124.1   -157.05 -145.58 -1.81   6.34    16
         +A1/S1 142.03  123.41  -156.23 -72.07  -19.45  -0.4    5.5
         ^<S2   134.29  121.27  -153.31 -76.28  -3.92   -2.37   3.8
         ^<S3   128.55  119.39  -152.31 -73.1   6.95    0.04    2.7
         ^<S4   120.87  115.88  -150.91 -69.62  8.05    0.63    2.7
         ^<S5   115.31  112.83  -151.31 -76.97  7.45    -2.31   2.4
         ^<S6   108.54  110.71  -149.38 -86.09  5.68    -6.48   1.5
     ^<S4       143.49  123.63  -155.79 -175.31 14.3    12.22   13.7
         +A1/S1 143.5   124.75  -155.22 175.69  25.35   25.61   5.9
         ^<S2   145.63  130.57  -156.39 141.67  42.19   31.94   5.3
         ^<S3   153.77  131.23  -153.8  71.9    34.43   20.11   3.6
         ^<S4   160.99  132.18  -149.31 89.71   35.44   14.31   2.6
         ^<S5   166.86  133.6   -146.6  93.88   34.73   11.46   1.8
         +A2/S1 143.63  122.79  -155.05 65.04   4.77    -16.93  3.5
         ^<S6   144.71  122.02  -151.41 56.49   -7.71   -16.1   2.8
         ^<S6   146.83  120.14  -148.52 61.14   24.37   48.58   2.9
         ^<S6   154.06  115.65  -149.29 60.87   20.18   13.8    2.5
     ^<S5       143.32  123.41  -153.16 -127.03 8.59    9.07    12.4
     ^<S6       143.49  121.69  -150.07 -127.26 9.04    10.85   12.5
```

It has only two changes respect the input:

- in row 8 (that is marked with the identifier `^<S4` in the second column) the `XX` value 27.76 has been replaced by the mean computed over the `XX` values from rows 5 to 12 (which have `+A1/S1`, `^<S2`, `^<S3`, `^<S4`, `^<S5`, `^<S6`, `^<S7`, `^<S8` in the second column as identifiers);
- in row 30 (that is marked with the identifier `^<S6` in the first column) the `YY` value 33.32 has been replaced by the mean computed over the `YY` values from the rows 3, 4, 13, 20, 30 and 31 (respectively marked with the identifiers `^/A1/S1`, `^<S2`, `^<S3`, `^<S4`, `^<S5`, `^<S6` in the first column).

The code I wrote so far follows. I thought of array of arrays, but I'm not sure about how to set it up.

Any suggestion is superwelcome as I'm superstuck.
Thank you!

```
open (HAN, "<", "$file") || die "problems with the input file";
    my @lines = ();
    while (<HAN>) { 
    chomp; 
    push(@lines, $_); }
    #print STDERR "@lines\n";

    close (HAN);
    for ($lines[$i] =0; $i<=$#lines; $i++){
        @columns = split (/\t/, $lines[$i]);
                #print STDERR "@columns\n";
    my @p;
    my @s;

    if (( $columns[0] ne "" ) && ( $columns[1] eq "" )){
            push @p, $lines[$i] ;       
                    #print STDERR "@p\n";
        } elsif (( $columns[0] eq "" ) && ( $columns[1] ne "" )){
            push @s, $lines[$i] ;       
                    #print  STDERR "@s\n";
        print STDERR "@s\n";
```

Comment: Hmm, but how should be handled lines 3-5 from the bottom -- all of them starts with `^<S6`? In all other samples numbers is sequential `^<S1`...`^<S8` for example.

Comment: You may move `my @p; my @s;` before for loop. In this way you could add multiple lines to the arrays. Then it could be possible to extract columns from the lines before the current line in order to calculate new values for replacement.

Comment: What is the criterion for doing the interpolation? For example, why is 27.76 replaced but 108.54 not? Are the columns in the data file tab or space separated? If the columns are tab separated, please provide a link to the data file so we can download it since copying it from here (in your question) will convert tabs to spaces and the formatting is lost

Comment: Following all the suggestions I updated my post. I will be pleased to receive help. thank you.

Comment: Why is 27.76 replaced? The mean of XX in its group is 155.72, dev.std is 55.38, so 27.67 > 155.72 - 3 * 55.38.

Comment: @choroba, you are right. I gave a wrong indication about interpolation: mean+/- 2 dev.st, not 3. I edit the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have more time to dedicate to this. Maybe the following can help you find the correct way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };
use Syntax::Construct qw{ // };

use List::Util qw{ sum };

my @data;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @data, [ split /\t/ ];
}

my (@dev_st, @mean);
for my $line_index (0 .. $#data) {
    for my $column (2, 3) {
        for my $level (0, 1) {
            if (($data[$line_index][$level] // "") =~ /A/) {
                my $to = $line_index;
                my $inner_group;
                do { ++$to } until $to > $#data
                             || $level == 1 && $data[$to][0]
                             || (($data[$to][$level] // "") =~ /A/
                                 and $inner_group = 1);
                --$to if $inner_group;

                my @group_data = map $data[$_][2],
                                 grep $data[$_][$level],
                                 $line_index .. $to;
                $mean[$level] = sum(@group_data) / @group_data;
                $dev_st[$level] = sqrt(1/(@group_data - 1) * sum(
                    map { ($_ - $mean[$level]) ** 2 } @group_data));
                # warn "$line_index: @group_data\n$mean[$level] $dev_st[$level]\n";
            }
        }

        my $value = $data[$line_index][$column] // "";
        next unless $value =~ /-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?/;

        my ($level) = grep $data[$line_index][$_], 0, 1;
        if (   $value > $mean[$level] + 2 * $dev_st[$level]
            || $value < $mean[$level] - 2 * $dev_st[$level]
        ) {
            $data[$line_index][$column]
                = sprintf '%.2f', $mean[$level];
        }
    }
    say join "\t", map $_ // "", @{ $data[$line_index] };
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: I think I don't have all technical background to understand properly what you are writing. You mean to handle the lines of a group by a loop? I don't know what ATM stands for...

Comment: ATM = at the moment.

Comment: Oh, wait, I misunderstood the spec. Fixing now.

Comment: Fixed. The mean of the group containing 27.76 is 155.72, not 173.59.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of how you could approach it:

```
package Main;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $self = Main->new( fn => 'in.mtg', save_fn => 'out.mtg');
$self->read_file();
$self->calc_mean();
$self->calc_std();
$self->do_subst();
$self->write_file();
say "Done";

sub do_subst {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    for my $i (0..2) {
        my $var = $self->{vars}[$i];
        my $mean = $self->{mean}[$i];
        my $std = $self->{std}[$i];
        for my $col_no (0..1) {
            my $col = $self->{col}[$col_no];
            $self->do_subst_col( $col, $var, $mean->[$col_no], $std->[$col_no] );
        }
    }
}

sub do_subst_col {
    my ( $self,  $col, $var, $mean, $std ) = @_;

    my $mean_cur;
    my $std_cur;
    my $k = 0;
    for my $i (0..$#$col) {
        my $id = $col->[$i];
        next if $id !~ /\S/;  # No identifier in this row
        if ( $id =~ /A/ ) {
            $k++ if defined $mean_cur;
            $mean_cur = $mean->[$k];
            $std_cur = $std->[$k];
        }
        if ( ($var->[$i] < ($mean_cur - 2*$std_cur))
             || ($var->[$i] > ($mean_cur + 2*$std_cur)) ) {
            $var->[$i] = $mean_cur;
        }
    }
}

sub calc_std {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my @std;
    for my $i (0..2) {
        push @std, $self->calc_std_var( $i );
    }
    $self->{std} = \@std;
}

sub calc_std_var {
    my ( $self,  $i ) = @_;

    my $mean = $self->{mean}[$i];
    my $var = $self->{vars}[$i];
    my @std;
    for my $col_no (0..1) {
        my $col = $self->{col}[$col_no];
        push @std, $self->calc_std_col( $col, $var, $mean->[$col_no] );
    }
    return \@std;
}

sub calc_std_col {
    my ( $self,  $col, $var, $mean ) = @_;

    my @std;
    my $sum;
    my $N;
    my $k = 0;
    my $mean_cur = $mean->[$k];
    for my $i (0..$#$col) {
        my $id = $col->[$i];
        next if $id !~ /\S/;  # No identifier in this row
        if ( $id =~ /A/ ) {
            if (defined $sum) {
                push @std, sqrt($sum/$N);
                $k++;
            }
            $sum = 0; $N = 0;
            $mean_cur = $mean->[$k];
        }
        $sum += ($var->[$i] - $mean_cur)**2;
        $N++;
    }
    push @std, sqrt($sum/$N);
    return \@std;
}

sub calc_mean {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my @mean;
    for my $i (0..2) {
        push @mean, $self->calc_mean_var( $i );
    }
    $self->{mean} = \@mean;
}

sub calc_mean_var {
    my ( $self,  $i ) = @_;

    my $var = $self->{vars}[$i];
    my @mean;
    for my $col_no (0..1) {
        my $col = $self->{col}[$col_no];
        push @mean, $self->calc_mean_col( $col, $var );
    }
    return \@mean;
}

sub calc_mean_col {
    my ( $self,  $col, $var ) = @_;

    my @mean;
    my $sum;
    my $N;
    for my $i (0..$#$col) {
        my $id = $col->[$i];
        next if $id !~ /\S/;  # No identifier in this row
        if ( $id =~ /A/ ) {
            push @mean, $sum/$N if defined $sum;
            $sum = 0; $N = 0;
        }
        $sum += $var->[$i];
        $N++;
    }
    push @mean, $sum/$N;
    return \@mean;
}

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;

    my $self = bless \%args, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub read_file {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $fn = $self->{fn};
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $line = $self->read_header( $fh );
    my @col1; my @col2; my @xx; my @yy; my @zz; my @rest;
    while (1) {
        chomp $line;
        my @F = split "\t", $line;
        die "Bad file." if @F != 9;
        push @col1, $F[0];
        push @col2, $F[1];
        push @xx, $F[2];
        push @yy, $F[3];
        push @zz, $F[4];
        push @rest, join "\t", @F[5..8];
        $line = <$fh>;
        last if !defined $line;
    }
    close $fh;
    $self->{col} = [\@col1, \@col2];
    $self->{vars} = [\@xx, \@yy, \@zz];
    $self->{rest} = \@rest;
    $self->{N} = scalar @col1;
}

sub read_header {
    my ( $self,  $fh ) = @_;

    my $line;
    my @header;
    while (1) {
        $line = <$fh>;
        die "Bad file." if !defined $line;
        last if $line =~ m{^ \^/A1/S1};
        push @header, $line;
    }
    $self->{header} = \@header;
    return $line;
}

sub write_file {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $fn = $self->{save_fn};
    open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print {$fh} join "", @{ $self->{header} };
    my $N = $self->{N};
    my $col1 = $self->{col}[0];
    my $col2 = $self->{col}[1];
    my $xx = $self->{vars}[0];
    my $yy = $self->{vars}[1];
    my $zz = $self->{vars}[2];
    my $rest = $self->{rest};
    for my $i (0..($N - 1)) {
        say {$fh} join "\t", $col1->[$i], $col2->[$i], $xx->[$i],
          $yy->[$i], $zz->[$i], $rest->[$i];
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: nice comprehensive approach, but there are some syntax errors aborting it

Comment: @Gabelins Thanks :) It works for me without any syntax errors. What errors do you get?

Comment: sorry, my fault...a clumsy editing. It is perfectly working, thank you

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your approach to input files which can have 2 or 3 columns of identifier. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Gabelins Can you send my a sample file? My email is in my profile. Then I will have a look at it.